# Trying to change div background colors in a specified sequence

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery's jquery.animate-colors-min.js plugin I am trying to change the background color of some div boxes in a sequence.

```
$('#firstbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow')
```

Above is what i used to animate the first box which works fine but i dont know how I would go about initiating a callback (if possible) to animate the background-color of the next specified box.

This below is just an example of something that woulda been great although as expected it does not work

```
    $('#firstbox').click(function(){

    $('#firstbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow'), function(){
                 $('#secondbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow');
        })
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
 $('#firstbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow'), function(){
     $('#secondbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow');
 })
```

should be:

```
 $('#firstbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow', function(){
     $('#secondbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow');
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#firstbox').click(function(){

    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow', function(){
                 $('#secondbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

animate() has three arguments

```
$('#firstbox').click(function(){
    $('#firstbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow', function(){
                 $('#secondbox').animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks your answer worked fine. If i wanted to animate 10 boxes in a callback function manner is there a easy way to put implement it inside a loop function instead of many duplicating lines of code? if you understand what i mean? thanks mate